# Spaces in FOR /R output

Tags: windows, xcopy

I need to copy a file `C:\plst.m3u` into all subfolders of `C:\Music`. I'm using this command:

```
FOR /R "C:\Music" %G IN (.) DO xcopy "C:\plst.m3u" %G
```

It works, but only for the paths, which doesn't contain spaces.

So, in the path `C:\Music\AB\`, it successfully creates `plst.m3u` in the `AB` folder. But for the path `C:\Music\A B\` it returns error: `invalid number of parameters`

Here, I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `%G` in xcopy otherwise it will pass `b\` as part of the xcopy command

**Example:**

> FOR /R "C:\Music" %G IN (.) DO xcopy "C:\plst.m3u" "%G"

---

**Why does this occur?**

The command that is passed is `DO xcopy "C:\plst.m3u" C:\Music\A B\` as there is no wrapping around the %G in the output

Because there is a space there it tries to pass the `b\` as part of the xcopy. Available switches for xcopy:

```
XCOPY source [destination] [/A | /M] [/D[:date]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
                           [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/G] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
                           [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z] [/B]
                           [/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...]
```

As `b\` is not a part of these switches it returns the error `invalid number of parameters`